# sorting an array of objects explained

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this Array of objects (snippit) -> from the state of my staff members.

Im running this as per example I got from [HERE](https://www.sitepoint.com/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/)

But on running it, it does nothing and stepping through it shows that `a` and `b` arguments are never initialized.

Im really dont understand how it works. Please can you explain whats happening without dissing me off to some duplicate. I want to understand this.

```
100:{mds_id: 291100176, mds_surname: "Kaal", mds_role: "Doctor", mds_grade: "CONS", mds_firstname: "", …}
101:{mds_id: 291100004, mds_surname: "Key", mds_role: "Nurse", mds_grade: "Clinical Nurse Specialist", mds_firstname: "Blogs", …}
102:{mds_id: 291100349, mds_surname: "Kendy", mds_role: "Doctor", mds_grade: "CONS", mds_firstname: "Fred", …}
103:{mds_id: 291100356, mds_surname: "Kin", mds_role: "Nurse", mds_grade: "", mds_firstname: "Roza", …}
104:{mds_id: 291100247, mds_surname: "Knit", mds_role: "Doctor", mds_grade: "CONS", mds_firstname: "", …}




getInitialState: function(){
    var state = {
        medicalstaffs:CustomizationStore.getMedicalstaffs(),

        header: {
            onClick: (field) => {
                var staff = this.state.medicalstaffs;
                var sortedStaff = staff.sort(this._compareValues(field, 'desc'));
                this.setState({medicalstaffs: sortedStaff});
            },
        }
    };
    return util.joinObjects(state,this.updatedLists());
},



_compareValues: function(key, order='asc') {
    return function(a, b) {
        if(!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // property doesn't exist on either object
            return 0;
        }

        const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string') ?
            a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
        const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string') ?
            b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];

        let comparison = 0;
        if (varA > varB) {
            comparison = 1;
        } else if (varA < varB) {
            comparison = -1;
        }
        return (
            (order == 'desc') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
        );
    };
},
```

Comment: Note that `sort` is an in place operation so you're mutating state.

Comment: Yes. that is what I want to achieve. This is a listing of staff members. so clicking on a header should sort by `this` column and update state and refresh thew component.

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I dont see why this is so ugly and worth down voting or closing without and explanation. Is this not a well structure question?

Comment: No not really, for example, I don't have a clue what exactly you do not understand? Note that you are creating a closure which will then only be executed upon clicking a header. So, `a` & `b` will be parameters of the callback for the `Array.prototype.sort` method, so a & b will be one item of the array at all times

Comment: Okay, but when I step through the code, I get `a is not defined` and `b is not defined`. This is what I question, why would they be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

My Solutions

```
        header: {
            onClick: (column) => {
                if(this.state.order === null || this.state.order === 'desc' ){
                    this.setState({order: 'asc'});
                } else {
                    this.setState({order: 'desc'});
                }

                const order = this.state.order;
                const key = column['property'];

                var byName = this.state.medicalstaffs.slice(0);
                byName.sort(function(a,b) {

                    const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string') ?
                        a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
                    const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string') ?
                        b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];

                    let comparison = 0;
                    if (varA > varB) {
                        comparison = 1;
                    } else if (varA < varB) {
                        comparison = -1;
                    }
                    return (
                        (order == 'desc') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
                    );

                });
                this.setState({medicalstaffs: byName});
            },
        }
```